# SharePoint 2007 - 2010 migration (What do the existing tools don't do ? )

Tags: sharepoint-2010

http://cmsreport.com/content/2010/03/ten-content-migration-tools-sharepoint-platform is a link that shows many software that exist migrating "content" from a 2007 to 2010 platform.

Barring web farm / sql server 32 - 64 bit issues, what is that which will NOT be migrated (assuming that I do a Attach / detach database upgrade method. In place upgrade is not an option in my farm.

I have a web farm with one app server and one sql server box.

Thanks in advance

Note: I did look at other similar posts but they did not have the kind of information that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following Technet article which should give you a starting point for planning your upgrade:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303429.aspx

The article should give you an idea of what to plan ahead for and what the pros and cons for each method would be.